# Is there a better way to make an EventManager

Tags: c++, sfml

I made a little code for my `EventManager`, it works correctly, but the thing is, I created it with a lot of copy-paste, and I think that every time you start doing copy-paste on a few lines, your code is badly designed.

So, having done a lot of copy-paste on that `EventManager`, I think it's time to find out if there is another way to make it (and there probably is, and probably better).

What I achieved is that when an Event happens (`window.pollEvent(event)`), it calls the `onEvent(sf::Event, sf::RenderWindow*)` method of the `EventManager` class, and for every event I need to listen, I call all instances of the listener.

Here's the class :

```
public:
    void registerKeyPressed(std::shared_ptr<KeyPressedEventListener> listener);
    void registerWindowResized(std::shared_ptr<WindowResizedEventListener> listener);
    void registerWindowFrameUpdate(std::shared_ptr<WindowFrameUpdateEventListener> listener);
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<KeyPressedEventListener>> m_keyPressedListeners;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<WindowResizedEventListener>> m_windowResizedListeners;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<WindowFrameUpdateEventListener>> m_windowFrameUpdateListeners;
```

So, the thing is, it is a lot of code for only 3 listeners (I currently have 6, but it's not useful to show them as the code is always similar).

My problem is that I want a class to be able to listen to one, two or more events at a time, so all my listeners have a different function that's called when the event happens. For example, these three listeners have the functions `onKeypressed(sf::Event);`, `onWindowResized(sf::Event, sf::RenderWindow* window);` and `onFrameUpdate(sf::RenderWindow* window);`. That's the only way I found to make this code work.

It actually works, but I'd like to make something better, because it's a lot of code for every event :

```
void EventManager::onEvent(sf::Event event, sf::RenderWindow* window) { // The window argument is used further, but it's not useful to show it here as the code is quite the same
    switch (event.type) {
    case sf::Event::Resized:
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_windowResizedListeners.size(); i++) {
            if (m_windowResizedListeners.at(i)->onWindowResized(event)) break; // The events return a bool value : True if the loop has to stop (for an error, for example), false otherwise. I always return false unless an error happen, but it's in case I need to stop it.
        }
        break;
    }
}
void EventManager::registerWindowResized(std::shared_ptr<WindowResizedEventListener> listener) {
    m_windowResizedListeners.push_back(listener);
}
```

And I have to duplicate this code for every event. If there's a bug, you understand it'll be a lot of work to correct it, so I hoped you could help me find a better way to achieve it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are not using window parameter in onEvent

Comment: I use it further, I just didn't want to show the code for the 6 listeners, as it's quite the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a common class:

```
class EventHandler{

public:

    virtual void handle(sf::RenderWindow &window) = 0;
};

class EventManager {

public:
    void registerKeyPressed(std::shared_ptr<EventHandler> listener);
    void registerWindowResized(std::shared_ptr<EventHandler> listener);
    void registerWindowFrameUpdate(std::shared_ptr<EventHandler> listener);
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<EventHandler>> m_keyPressedListeners;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<EventHandler>> m_windowResizedListeners;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<EventHandler>> m_windowFrameUpdateListeners;
}
```

You can now define a map in the class, the key is the event type and the value is his listener's vector.

```
    std::map<int,std::vector<std::shared_ptr<EventHandler>>*> eventType;
}

//...

EventManager::EventManager(){
    eventType[sf::EventType::Resized] = &m_windowResizedListeners;
    eventType[sf::EventType::KeyPressed] = &m_keyPressedListeners;

    //Keep going...
}
```

So now, the onEvent function is pretty straightforward:

```
void EventManager::onEvent(sf::Event event, sf::RenderWindow* window) {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<EventHandler>>* ptr = eventType[event.type];
    for (int i = 0;i < ptr->size();i++)
        (*ptr)[i]->handle(window);
}
```

Let's put an example:

```
class SettingsSaver : public EventHandler{

   public:
       void handle(sf::RenderWindow &window) override {
           std::cout << "I am saving the state in the hardrive before of exit" << std::endl;
       }
}

class MoveHero : public EventHandler{

   public:
       void handle(sf::RenderWindow &window) override {
           std::cout << "I am moving the character" << std::endl;
       }
}

// Main

std::shared_ptr<EventHandler> settingsSaver(new SettingsSaver);
std::shared_ptr<EventHandler> moveHero(new MoveHero);

EventManager manager;
manager.registerWindowClosed(settingsSaver);
manager.registerKeyPressed(moveHero);
```

Comment: Mmh thanks ! But how can I make a class listening to, let's say, `keyPressed` and `windowResized` events ? Sorry, I'm kinda bad :c

Comment: *The client* should extend EventHandler class and define the behaviour of handle() function. I assume that you know "polymorphism" and "abstract clases".

Comment: Yes I know it ^^ I just didn't know how to know which Event it was, but I think I will only use the sf::Event parameter to check the event in the handle() function.

Comment: @MegalovaniaPowa no no no, i will update my answer with an example

Comment: @MegalovaniaPowa check it up now :)

Comment: Erm, but couldn't we just create one class which listens to many events ?

Comment: You shouldn't need check the event's type in the handle function,

Comment: Because I actually need my classes to listen to 2-3 events at once ^^ for example a button need to handle the onClick event and the onMouseMove event ^^

Comment: @MegalovaniaPowa that's not smart. Differents events mean diferrents behaviours, so you should hold it in differents places.

The key here is that you can reuse EventManager in everywhere. You only has to subcribe to the events that you want.

Comment: That's why I created different functions, but I guess the handle thing is smarter, even though I'd like to subscribe many events at once ^^